# Is there any way to display more than one value of a schema using displayProperty

Tags: javascript

The `displayProperty` field of the schema only accepts a single property name, but I'd like to be able to display more than one value in the chip.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, no. The `displayProperty` can only point to a single property. You can however create a new property which joins together the values from fields in the API response, and use that as the `displayProperty`. For example:

```
let LocationSchema = coda.makeObjectSchema({
  properties: {
    city: { type: coda.ValueType.String },
    state: { type: coda.ValueType.String },
    // Add an additional property to use as the display value.
    display: { type: coda.ValueType.String },
    // ...
  },
  displayProperty: "display",
  // ...
});

pack.addFormula({
  // ...
  resultType: coda.ValueType.Object,
  schema: LocationSchema,
  execute: async function([], context) {
    let location = await fetchLocationFromAPI(context);
    return {
      city: location.city,
      state: location.state,
      // Populate the display value using data from the API.
      display: location.city + ", " + location.state,
    },
  },
});
```

More information is available in the documentation:
https://coda.io/packs/build/latest/guides/advanced/schemas/#display-value